# Search Query in RavenDB

Tags: linq, ravendb

I would like to know the Search Query for the below condition. I have created an index called MeetingEventIndex as below:

```
public class MeetingEventIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<mngtMeetingEvent>
 {
  public MeetingEventIndex ()
  {
     Map = docs => from d in docs select new {d.meetingroomid, d.text, d.details};

     Index(x=>x.meetingroomid, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
     Index(x=>x.text, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
     Index(x=>x.details, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
  }
 }
```

I am trying to create a search query as below "**Search the term in text or details field and meetingroomid==123**"

```
docsession.Query<mngtMeetingEvent, MeetingEventIndex>()
.Search(x=>x.text , search)
.Search(x=>x.details, search. options: SearchOptions.Or)
.Search(x=>x.meetingroomid, "123", option.SearchOptions.And)
.ToList()
```

But this is not returning any result.

Basically I am looking for ((searchterm in text field || searchterm in details field ) and mrcode in meetingroomid field).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is probably more easily expressed as LuceneQuery, instead:

```
docsession.Advanced..LuceneQuery<mngtMeetingEvent, MeetingEventIndex>()
   .OpenSubClause()
       .Search("text", search)
       .OrElse()
       .Search("details", search)
   .CloseSubClause()
   .AndAlso()
   .WhereEquals("meetingroomid", "123")
   .ToList();
```